# Issue with Metamask's eth_requestAccounts giving an array containing a single account

Tags: metamask

I am trying to retrieve the accounts the user selects with Metamask.

Here is my code:

```
const ethereum = window['ethereum'];

const requestPermissions = ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_requestPermissions',
  params: [{ eth_accounts: {} }]
});

const requestAccounts = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

requestPermissions
  .then(() => requestAccounts)
  .then(res => console.log('result: ', res));//Only one account is listed here (the first selected)
```

The above `requestAccounts` result contains a single account although the user has selected several accounts.

What I am getting wrong?

**edit**: I noticed that the **`eth_requestAccounts`** only returns an array containing a single element (see documentation here: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts). Then what method are we supposed to use in order to get array containing the selected accounts?

Answer (score 1):

This is a MetaMask design decision based on security reasons see [doc](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts) although the original [EIP-1102](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1102.md#eth_requestaccounts) requires that the `eth_requestAccounts` method returns one or more accounts if approved.

Comment: Get it, `...more accounts if approved`, but how do I approve?